# How to turn on screen saver with chrome remote desktop?

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop

I've installed Chrome Remote desktop https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en

So I connect to my laptop at home from work. Then I check something on the web. Go out. Go home. See on my laptop that the remote session is still on. SCREEN SAVER NOT ENGAGED. The entire LCD screen is burnt.

So apparently, Chrome Remote Desktop prevents the screen saver from engaging. How could I enable it? I don't want to end the remote session all the time, because I use it frequently during the day. But when I don't use it say for an hour, I don't want my laptop's screen burnt.

---

I've tried to close the lid of my laptop, so that the screen is turned off during remote session, but in this case, I cannot right click, because the pop-ups do not appear. In fact, most windows do not seem to display properly. I have to lift the lid for the screen to turn on and display everything all right.

---

It seems if I open Chrome Remote Desktop in a browser tab as opposed to a new window, then the screen saver engages. That means using it in a new window, as suggested by a nice "tip" by CRD, it will ruin your laptop's screen. Will have to test this out.

Comment: CRD intentionally disables your system's screen saver while you're remotely connected (if it didn't, then you wouldn't be able to interact with it if the screen saver engaged while you were connected), but it should restore normal settings once you disconnect. Are you observing that the screen saver never comes on while you're connected to your computer remotely, or after having disconnected?

Comment: @user238289 when connected and the session is idle

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using Curtain Mode. The screen saver should continue to run on the host computer, and the screen will appear locked.

On Windows:
Set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\RemoteAccessHostRequireCurtain to 1.
Enable RDP connections to the machine by selecting Control Panel\System and Security\System > Remote settings > "Allow connections from computers running any version of Remote Desktop (less secure)".

https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2799701?hl=en